# Locally save data using firestore and sync later

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, polymer-2.x, polymerfire

I am facing an issue integrating the offline behavior of google firestore into my polymer application.

I have created an element to preform all the database operation with firestore. I have initialized the connection in the constructor and below is code.

```
constructor() {
            super();
            if (!this.db) {
                firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
                    .then(() => {
                        this.db = firebase.firestore();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
                        } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
```

I have created another function which saves user details to firestore.

```
saveUserAndSync() {
            this.db.collection("users").add(this.userObj)
                .then(function (docRef) {
                    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });
        }
```

This works great even if it is offline. The biggest problem that i am facing is if the application is offline and i create user and at the same time if i reload the page all the data is lost and the sync with firestore wont work.

Can anyone suggest a work around for this.

I was able to do the same implementation using pouchDB and couchDB, as pouchDB api will first save the data locally and then sync it with couchDB.

But with firestore it fails.

Comment: Hello everyone, just a small update. I was able to make it work using the enablePersistence() if the app is offline. The only problem that i facing is not to make it work if i reload the page. But the data does gets stored in indexedDB of firebase. But the sync only happens if initiate another action. Can anyone suggest me how to sync when the app is back online. Or am i missing any configuration to make this working.

Answer (score 0):

For web application, offline storage is not enabled by default.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable
>   persistence, call the enablePersistence method. Cloud Firestore's
>   cache isn't automatically cleared between sessions. Consequently, if
>   your web app handles sensitive information, make sure to ask the user
>   if they're on a trusted device before enabling persistence.
>
> Important: For the web, offline persistence is an experimental feature
>   that is supported only by the Chrome, Safari, and Firefox web
>   browsers. Also, if a user opens multiple browser tabs that point to
>   the same Cloud Firestore database, and offline persistence is enabled,
>   Cloud Firestore will work correctly only in the first tab.

What you're seeing is the expected behavior until you enable persistence.

Comment: I have enabled persistence in the constructor by calling firebase.firestore().enablePersistence(), but still data is not saved locally and gets cleared if you reload the page.

Comment: Hi @Doug Stevenson, just a small update. I was able to make it work using the **enablePersistence()** if the app is offline. The only problem that i facing is not to make it work if i reload the page. But the data does gets stored in **indexedDB** of firebase. But the sync only happens if initiate another action. Can anyone suggest me how to sync when the app is back online. Or am i missing any configuration to make this working. Thanks in advance.